# Periodically sending data over sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets

I have made a multi-client server, which uses select() to determine what clients are currently sending. However, I am wanting to send data that is larger than my buffer size (e.g. text from a file) while remaining a non-blocking client.

At first I have found solutions that place the send/recv into while loops to send the data, with the while loop condition being the amount of bytes sent, but wouldn't that block the server for a certain amount of time? Especially if the contents of the file is large?

I was thinking to send say 1024bytes in one iteration of my server while loop, and then on the next iteration it sends the next 1024bytes to the client etc. Although this would have consequences on the client side. Possibly the client could ask for the next **x** bytes per query to the server?

Please let me know if there is a standard way to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: Essentially, you have to write your own state-machine to correctly implement your file transer, or whatever, protocol across the interleaved communications/ completions from all the clients.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything special for this.  Your sockets are presumably already configured as non-blocking, so when you write to them, pass as much data as you have, and check the return value to see how much was actually sent.  Then keep the rest of the data in a buffer, and wait until the file descriptor is ready again before attempting to write more.

Comment: Well, 'keep the rest of the data in a buffer' yes, a buffer per socket fd, and a buffer index per socket fd, and an fd for the file per socket fd.  It's not quite as trivial-sounding as 'You don't need to do anything special for this' implies:(

Comment: @MartinJames: The buffering is the same as you'd need to support the case where the client wasn't ready to receive the very first byte.